# HP dv6-3216 won't turn on

Tags: hardware-failure

Replaced the screen myself to save money.  Took forever to reattach all the cables and now it won't turn on. I unplugged 2 cables: the power cable and the cable nearest the mouse to remove the keyboard. I know I put those two back in place, but won't turn on with the battery or power cord. What else could be the issue?

Comment: Disassemble and double check your work, did you get the power button cable re-attached properly?

Comment: I recently tore apart an old HP laptop to quiet a noisy fan.  There were so many connections that when I got it back together the fan didn't run at all.  Second disassembly located the connection I failed to make.  It's tedious, but I suggest you do it again.  Take your time and read the maintenance manual at each step.

Comment: @techie007 - I applaud Tonya's willingness to dig in and give it a try. Cheer up.